# PHP Regular Expression For The Dynamically Generated String

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a regular expression in php for the dynamically generated string.

Below is the my use case -

```
$str1 = {"testste", "comma", etc......};
```

The above string not a static, it will be change every time.

```
$str2 =  "huge log string";
```

The above string as well generated dynamically.

I have converted the $str1 to array as it is comma separated.

Now created a function to check $str1 array items into $str2

```
   public function arrayInString($findArrayItems , $findinString){
        $flag = false;
        foreach($findArrayItems as $item){
            if((($item!='') && strpos($findinString, $item)!==false)){
                $flag = true;
            }
        }
        return $flag;
   }
```

This is what I am using currently.

How I can write the regular expression to avoid the use of function arrayInString if both $str1 and $str2 are generating dynamically.

Comment: [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand you at all... What's wrong with doing `arrayInString( $str1, $str2 );`?

Comment: @AeroX, Nothing is wrong using the arrayInString( $str1, $str2 );
Just curious to know if it is possible in PHP..

Comment: How about using `explode()` and `in_array()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array just contains words or phrases that you wish to match as is (i.e. they don't contain regex patterns).  Then you can use a `foreach()` to build a regex pattern using `preg_quote()` on each item in the array.

Your original `arrayInString()` function may perform better then this though as Regex comes with an overhead.

```
$arr = array("One", "Two", "Three");
$str1 = "This is a Non-Match";
$str2 = "This one is a Match";

$first = true;
$regex = "/\b(?:";
foreach( $arr as $item ) {
    $regex .= ($first?"":"|") . preg_quote( $item, '/' );
    if($first) {$first = false;}
}
$regex .= ")\b/i";

// Regex is now equal to "/\b(?:One|Two|Three)\b/i"

print "Str1: " . (preg_match($regex, $str1)?"Matches":"Doesn't Match");
print "Str2: " . (preg_match($regex, $str2)?"Matches":"Doesn't Match");
```

This produced a Regular Expression which does the following:
[image: Regular expression visualization]